# store permissions and roles in laravel-persmission mongodb and jenssegers

Tags: mongodb, laravel, permissions

i using [jenssegers-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) and [laravel-permission-mongodb](https://github.com/mostafamaklad/laravel-permission-mongodb). when i try to store a permission that assigned to roles ([image is here](https://ibb.co/nQ2L4o)), the permission stored but the roles that have this permission, not update and permission dont assign to role

my code to store permission:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=>'required|max:40',
    ]);
    $permission = new Permission();
    $permission->name = $request->name;
    $permission->save();

    if ($request->roles <> '') { 
        foreach ($request->roles as $key=>$value) {
            $role = Role::find($value);
            $role->permissions()->attach($permission);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('permissions.index')->with('success','Permission added successfully');

}
```

sorry for bad English :(